# How to pass multiple parameter via PHP header?

Tags: php, http-headers

Can I use header to pass multiple parameters or just one?

I am trying to implement this but its not working, It doesn't navigate:

```
    $selected_company = $_POST['company_name'];
    $company_type = $_POST['company_type'];
    $url_param = "comp_id=$selected_company&comp_type=$company_type";
    header("location: ./create_user.php?$url_param");
```

Whats wrong with the code I am using?
If I want to pass only want parameter I can do it like this and it works:

```
   header("location: ./create_user.php?$selected_company");
```

P.S. it is so strange that I was not able to find one single working solution to this, I assumed this is a very common issue.

Comment: It looks like it should work.  In what way does this fail?

Comment: The Location header just specifies a URL. The URL can be any valid URL containing as many querystring parameters as you like. If it's failing it's not because of any restriction on the Location header

Comment: Have you debugged and checked what the final URL looks like? It's possible that the variables need url-encoding, for example. You should be doing that anyway as a matter of course to avoid potential problems

Comment: @ADyson yea I think I was having another problem and thinking its the header. Here is where I am kindda stuck: `<option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?><?php echo $row['company_type'] ?>"> <?php echo $row['company_name']; ?> </option>; `how can I POST both of those values when I submit form? I need them separated so that I can catch them when submitted.

Comment: Ok so actually you're asking about posting back form fields rather than constructing a URL? That is a somewhat different issue.

Comment: But its not clear why you need to submit multiple values there...if you submit the ID which is the value in the option, then that should allow you to identify the rest of the associated values (i.e. type and name) by looking it up - in your database I would assume. You don't need to submit all the values, that's the whole purpose of having a unique ID, and is a very standard use for a drop-down list

Comment: @ADyson actually in this case I do need to submit both ids

Comment: @ttt: The question you're asking above and the question you're asking in the comments are two completely different questions, and both a bit incomplete.  Please update the question above to indicate what it is you're asking and what specifically isn't working.

Comment: @ttt Why exactly? Your create user script should be able to look up the company type in the database based on the company ID. And it should not be relying on user input to suggest that value anyway, it should be fixed and not be influenceable - otherwise a malicious user could use this script to set an incorrect value during this execution, so it doesn't match what's in the database. I can't see any reason why you should need or want to pass the company type in this script, it goes against all standard practice as far as I can see. If you have a genuine justification it would be interesting.

Answer (score -1):

Try out this and it worked for me:

```
<?php

$selected_company = $_POST['company_name'];
$company_type = $_POST['company_type'];
$url_param = "comp_id=$selected_company&comp_type=$company_type";
header("location: ./create_user.php?".$url_param);
?>
```

Also checkout the value coming from `POST` parameters;

Comment: I think you've missed the fact that the focus of the discussion has changed somewhat - read the comments. This was never the real issue. Granted the OP should have updated their question, but also you should read what's going on before answering :-)